# How to prevent button moving when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script>


function Show(element){
element.style.display = "block";
}


function Hide(element){
element.style.display = "none";
}


function Slide(){

try{

img1 = img1id.style.display;
img2 = img2id.style.display;
img3 = img3id.style.display;

if(img1 =="none" && img2=="none"){
Show(img1id);
Hide(img3id);
}

else if(img2 == "block" && img1=="none"){
Hide(img2id)
Show(img3id);
}

else if(img3 == "block" && img1 == "none" && img2 == "none"){
Show(img1id);
Hide(img3id); 
}

else {
Hide(img1id);
Hide(img3id);
Show(img2id);
}

}

catch(e){
alert("Evento " + e);

}

}


var img1id;
var img2id;
var img3id;
var buttonid;


function gestoreLoad(){
try{

img1id = document.getElementById("id1");
img2id = document.getElementById("id2");
img3id = document.getElementById("id3");
buttonid = document.getElementById("id4");
buttonid.onclick = Slide;

}
catch(e) {
alert("gestoreLoad " + e);
}
}

window.onload = gestoreLoad;
</script>
<style type="text/css">

button:active {
  padding: 0px;
}

button#id4 {
 margin: auto auto auto auto;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 80px;
 width: 150px;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
 border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}


img {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
 </style>
</head>
<center>
<img id="id1" style="width:800px; height:400px;" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beatiful-nature-lake-forest-pang-260nw-1039096585.jpg" />
<img id="id2" style="display:none; width:800px; height:400px;" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/fragment-traditional-iranian-architecture-against-beatiful-purple-sky-yellow-pink-clouds-beautiful-sunset-iranian-122642415.jpg" />
<img id="id3" style="display:none; width:800px; height:400px;" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5808/21804482933_2b1279ef62_b.jpg" />
</center>

<br />
<center>
<button id="id4" /><span>Slideshow!</span></button>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

I take some images from internet for the example.
Btw when I click for the first time on the button (so after page's load), it moves up...Do you know any solutions?

P.s I know in W3chools there are the codes for slideshow which work perfectly, but I would try by myself and to learn more about JavaScript for fun

Comment: The button doesn't move for me (Firefox and Chrome)

Comment: Ok..so the problem it's only with chrome, isn't it? Btw you know any solutions? @D.Pardal

Comment: It doesnt jump up. Since the first image has text with a white background and the others dont, it looks like it does.

Comment: No repro in Chrome.  What you might be seeing is the shadow being moved from the lower right to the upper left.  It simulates a button push.

Comment: the button in the snippet doesn't move for me either - in chrome.  what do you mean by move?  changes position permanently after being clicked - or just while the mouse is down? i think you are seeing the borders changing as you click it

Comment: It looks like it is with the height of the first image, change the first image and try doing the same

Comment: I mean when you click for the first time the button, despite the width and the height of the images, which are exactly the same, the button "jump" a bit up (but if you re click, this behaviour doesn't happens). In my real code i have image without text, so the text it's not the problem @Josh

Comment: Yes I observed that, let me look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the things I observed:

1. The button you used is incorrect, I have modified that as well.
2. You have to go through the `JavaScript` method you wrote basically this is reason why a button was flickering for the first time, why?
   That is because when first click event happen it always goes to last `else` condition and it was making the first image hidden and the button started to move up by that time other `show()` brings the image back to its position. now if you think why it was not happening for the second and third click's that is because the first image now has a `display` property either as `none` or `block`.

For the very first time, the display property for the first image is always `null` you can validate it by adding `alert()` you will get to know, so to fix the issue what I have made, since you want the first image to be displayed during page load, hence I have used `display:block;` for the first image in the inline query, so when you click on the button for the first time instead of returning the null value now it returns `block` as a property and hence it stops the button to move up.

I guess you got what I am trying to convey here, if not we can connect.

below is the working code(feel free to modify things)

```js
function Show(element) {
  element.style.display = "block";
}


function Hide(element) {
  element.style.display = "none";
}


function Slide() {

  try {

    img1 = img1id.style.display;
    img2 = img2id.style.display;
    img3 = img3id.style.display;

    if (img1 === "none" && img2 == "none") {
      Show(img1id);
      Hide(img3id);
    } else if (img2 == "block" && img1 == "none") {
      Hide(img2id)
      Show(img3id);
    } else if (img3 == "block" && img1 == "none" && img2 == "none") {
      alert("none");
      Show(img1id);
      Hide(img3id);
    } else {
      Hide(img1id);
      Hide(img3id);
      Show(img2id);
    }

  } catch (e) {
    alert("Evento " + e);

  }

}


var img1id;
var img2id;
var img3id;
var buttonid;


function gestoreLoad() {
  try {

    img1id = document.getElementById("id1");
    img2id = document.getElementById("id2");
    img3id = document.getElementById("id3");
    buttonid = document.getElementById("id4");
    buttonid.onclick = Slide;

  } catch (e) {
    alert("gestoreLoad " + e);
  }
}

window.onload = gestoreLoad;
```

```css
button:active {
  padding: 0px;
}

button#id4 {
  margin: auto auto auto auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 80px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

img {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Firefox < 16 */

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Internet Explorer */

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Opera < 12.1 */

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<center>
  <img id="id1" style="display:block; width:800px; height:400px;" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beatiful-nature-lake-forest-pang-260nw-1039096585.jpg" />
  <img id="id2" style="display:none; width:800px; height:400px;" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/fragment-traditional-iranian-architecture-against-beatiful-purple-sky-yellow-pink-clouds-beautiful-sunset-iranian-122642415.jpg" />
  <img id="id3" style="display:none; width:800px; height:400px;" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5808/21804482933_2b1279ef62_b.jpg" />
</center>
<br />
<center>
  <button id="id4" type="button">Slideshow!</button>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding `border: 0` to `button#id4` do the trick. At least in Firefox and Chrome.

BTW [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tag is obsolete. You should use CSS to center your content.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script>


function Show(element){
element.style.display = "block";
}


function Hide(element){
element.style.display = "none";
}


function Slide(){

try{

img1 = img1id.style.display;
img2 = img2id.style.display;
img3 = img3id.style.display;

if(img1 =="none" && img2=="none"){
Show(img1id);
Hide(img3id);
}

else if(img2 == "block" && img1=="none"){
Hide(img2id)
Show(img3id);
}

else if(img3 == "block" && img1 == "none" && img2 == "none"){
Show(img1id);
Hide(img3id); 
}

else {
Hide(img1id);
Hide(img3id);
Show(img2id);
}

}

catch(e){
alert("Evento " + e);

}

}


var img1id;
var img2id;
var img3id;
var buttonid;


function gestoreLoad(){
try{

img1id = document.getElementById("id1");
img2id = document.getElementById("id2");
img3id = document.getElementById("id3");
buttonid = document.getElementById("id4");
buttonid.onclick = Slide;

}
catch(e) {
alert("gestoreLoad " + e);
}
}

window.onload = gestoreLoad;
</script>
<style type="text/css">

button:active {
  padding: 0px;
}

button#id4 {
 margin: auto auto auto auto;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 80px;
 width: 150px;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
    border: 0;
 border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}


img {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
 </style>
</head>
<center>
<img id="id1" style="width:800px; height:400px;" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beatiful-nature-lake-forest-pang-260nw-1039096585.jpg" />
<img id="id2" style="display:none; width:800px; height:400px;" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/fragment-traditional-iranian-architecture-against-beatiful-purple-sky-yellow-pink-clouds-beautiful-sunset-iranian-122642415.jpg" />
<img id="id3" style="display:none; width:800px; height:400px;" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5808/21804482933_2b1279ef62_b.jpg" />
</center>

<br />
<center>
<button id="id4" /><span>Slideshow!</span></button>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it still happen if you open full screen you can see the movement.

Comment: @JustAnotherSimpleProgrammer__ sorry my laptop shutdown yesterday, I have fixed the issue! you can check my answer :) let me know.